# Mathematica shift-enter problem

Tags: evaluation, notebooks

Would really appreciate if someone can help with this problem:

When I first open a Mathematica note book, say you do 1+2 and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. As expected, I get "3" as the output.

Now suppose you want to 4+5. But after pressing shift-enter, the program just sits on it, without giving 9 as the answer.

Only way to get the output was to abort the evaluation, and to re-execute it.

This happens for any other calculation (other than the very first one you run in the session). What this means that every calculation I have to do twice to get the output.

This has never happened to me in last 25 years of use, and I cannot seem to find the problem. Even uninstalled the program and reinstalled it and still doing the same thing.

By the way, I am running Mathematica version 9(64bit) on Windows 7 Professional (64bit)

Thank you so much for any help.

Tim

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: I think there is a way to reset all MMA settings. I cant remember which post, but definitely has been asked before.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange.  Please reserve the `bugs` tag for problems either confirmed by Wolfram employees as a bug or considered a bug by community consensus, even in cases like this one which really seem like a bug.

Comment: As @ChenStatsYu comments you should try a reset as described here: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3274 -- I hope it works as that's a nasty problem. :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yap, that's the link I was just trying to pin down. I remember seeing it on a similar post.

Comment: Also, if you are using a recent version, try disabling the Suggestions Bar, as it has been the source of many problems.  Try also `$HistoryLength = 0;`

Comment: Thanks to both of your responses, Mr. Wizard and Mr. Chen.  On Monday when I go back to my work place (the problem is at the work computer), I will try your suggestion.  More like, I will show your suggestion to colleagues in my computer support division - they will know how to follow your suggestion.  I will let you know whether it will work or not.  By the way, have you ever heard of an identical problem happening to someone else? Thank you so much for your time in advance. Tim

Comment: "ever heard of an identical problem" -- not that I recall, but my memory is notoriously poor.

Comment: i have had this exact issue in the past.  Sometimes restarting the kernel a dozen times was required before being able to work normally. Unfortunately i cant tell you much more though, it went away on the last upgrade (to 9.0.1).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been abandoned by the OP. Further, it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.